# What "ment" means in "incrementum"

Tags: etymology, meaning

What "ment" means in "incrementum"?

On [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/incrementum) I have found meaning of only first parts of the word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suffix *-mentum* (neuter, genitive *-menti*) is used to indicate an instrument or result.
It appears to be a productive way to derive nouns from verbs.
It even has [its own Wiktionary page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-mentum), but I admit it is hard to find if you don't know you should be looking for it.
(If anyone here works with Wiktionary, I suggest adding a link to *-mentum* from *incrementum* to show both parts in the etymology section.)

There are [lots of Latin words ending in *-mentum*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=end&lookup=mentum&lang=la), for example:

- *instrumentum* < *instruere*
- *documentum* < *docere*
- *alimentum* < *alere*
- *argumentum* < *arguere*

There is also the related suffix [*-men*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-men) (neuter, genitive *-minis*) which gives rise to *volumen* (< *volvere*) and *flumen* (< *fluere*), among [others](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=end&lookup=men&lang=la).
The two suffixes are not identical, though, but they are sometimes interchangeable (e.g. *medicamen* ≈ *medicamentum*).